# jQuery animate scrolltop() not scrolling downwards in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I apply this code and test this in Internet Explorer and FireFox, on click, the page does not scroll down with the toggle function, but it does scroll back up after closing the overlay. This works fine in Google Chrome, but not in IE 10 or Firefox. Please help. :)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){


 $(".PlaceHolders").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
$(".overlay").slideToggle(2000, function(){

  $("#url_placeholder").text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Close Components" : "View Available Components");
});
   $('html','body').animate({scrollTop: $(".PlaceHolders").offset().top}, 2000);
 });
```

Comment: I have never seen a selector like `$('html','body')` before and it reads as if you're looking for an `<html>` tag inside a `<body>` tag. If you're trying to select both, can you try changing it to `$('html, body')`? That may be your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this is what you had wanted.
Here's a working fiddle, tested in chrome and ie10,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".PlaceHolders").click(function(e){

$(".overlay").slideToggle("slow", function() {

 setTimeout(function(){
   $("#url_placeholder").text($(this).parent(".overlay").is(':visible') ? "Close Components" : "View Available Components");
  },500);
  });

  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#url_placeholder").offset().top }, 1000);

e.preventDefault();
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adhegde001/8uf9pvqw/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's just your selector. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYNZzW

```
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(".PlaceHolders").offset().top}, 2000);
```